# Thrift python - TApplicationException: Invalid method name

Tags: python, thrift

I have 2 services that are defined in the same thrift file and share a port. I can use any method from serviceA no problem but whenever i try to call any of ServiceB's methods i get the exception.
this is my thrift file (service-a.thrift):

```
service ServiceA extends common.CommonService {
    list<i64> getByIds(1: list<i64> ids)
    ...
}

service ServiceB extends common.CommonService {
    list<i64> getByIds(1: list<i64> ids)
    ...
}
```

notes:

- I'm working with a python client
- Thrift version 0.8.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no straightforward way to bind several services to a single port without adding this field to TMessage and recompiling thrift. If you want to have two services using the same Server, you should reimplement Thrift Server, which it doesn't seem an easy task

Answer (score 1):

We had this need as well and solved by writing a new implementation of TProcessor that creates a map of multiple processors. The only gotcha is that with this implementation you need to ensure no method names overlap - i.e. don't use nice generic names like Run() in different servers. Apologies on not converting C# to Python...

Example Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Thrift;
using Thrift.Protocol;

/// <summary>
/// Processor that allows for multiple services to run under one roof.  Requires no method name conflicts across services.
/// </summary>
public class MultiplexProcessor : TProcessor {

    public MultiplexProcessor(IEnumerable<TProcessor> processors) {
        ProcessorMap = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<TProcessor, Delegate>>();
        foreach (var processor in processors) {
            var processMap = (IDictionary) processor.GetType().GetField("processMap_", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(processor);
            foreach (string pmk in processMap.Keys) {
                var imp = (Delegate) processMap[pmk];
                try {
                    ProcessorMap.Add(pmk, new Tuple<TProcessor, Delegate>(processor, imp));
                }
                catch (ArgumentException) {
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Method already exists in process map: {0}", pmk));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected readonly Dictionary<string, Tuple<TProcessor, Delegate>> ProcessorMap;

    internal protected Dictionary<string, Tuple<TProcessor, Delegate>> GetProcessorMap() {
        return new Dictionary<string, Tuple<TProcessor, Delegate>>(ProcessorMap);
    }

    public bool Process(TProtocol iprot, TProtocol oprot) {
        try {
            TMessage msg = iprot.ReadMessageBegin();
            Tuple<TProcessor, Delegate> fn;
            ProcessorMap.TryGetValue(msg.Name, out fn);
            if (fn == null) {
                TProtocolUtil.Skip(iprot, TType.Struct);
                iprot.ReadMessageEnd();
                var x = new TApplicationException(TApplicationException.ExceptionType.UnknownMethod, "Invalid method name: '" + msg.Name + "'");
                oprot.WriteMessageBegin(new TMessage(msg.Name, TMessageType.Exception, msg.SeqID));
                x.Write(oprot);
                oprot.WriteMessageEnd();
                oprot.Transport.Flush();
                return true;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Invoking service method {0}.{1}", fn.Item1, fn.Item2);
            fn.Item2.Method.Invoke(fn.Item1, new object[] {msg.SeqID, iprot, oprot});
        }
        catch (IOException) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
        Processor = new MultiplexProcessor(
            new List<TProcessor> {
                                     new ReportingService.Processor(new ReportingServer()),
                                     new MetadataService.Processor(new MetadataServer()),
                                     new OtherService.Processor(new OtherService())
                                 }
            );
        Server = new TThreadPoolServer(Processor, Transport);
```